# Why aren't all the product cards within the list wrapper?

Tags: html, css

Question is straightforward. Why aren't the product cards "flowing" to the right? The second product card isn't within the list-wrapper.

Extra question (maybe related): is there anything wrong with my choice of where to put my divs?

```css
.list-wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  left-margin: 5em;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
}

.product-card {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="list-wrapper">
    <div class="product-card">
      <ol>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="product-name">Product Name</div>
          <div class="product-basic-description">Comes in many colors and sizes</div>
          <div class=product-price>300.00 $</div>
          <div class=product-image><img src="" alt="{{ image-description }}"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-card">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="product-name">Product Name</div>
      <div class="product-basic-description">Comes in many colors and sizes</div>
      <div class=product-price>300.00 $</div>
      <div class=product-image><img src="" alt="{{ image-description }}"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</ol>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your HTML is wrong

Comment: @LaljiTadhani as you correctly saw the markup indeed is wrong, but besides stating that fact, telling the author _whats_ wrong would have helped much more.

Comment: Redoing the HTML worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are some nesting errors in your html.

The `<ol>` right in `product`-card is never properly closed and the last three closing tags (`</ol>` and 2x `</div>`) are loose and dont have a opening counterpart.

In addition you're defining an ordered list using `<ol>` but never use the list-item tags inside (`<li>`). See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) on details but heres how list markup in general should look:

> ```
> <ol>
>   <li>Mix flour, baking powder, sugar, and salt.</li>
>   <li>In another bowl, mix eggs, milk, and oil.</li>
>   <li>Stir both mixtures together.</li>
>   <li>Fill muffin tray 3/4 full.</li>
>   <li>Bake for 20 minutes.</li>
> </ol>
> ```

(Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol)

As it seems the `ol` element isnt neccessary for what youre trying to achieve, therefore i removed it.

Also i fixed the nesting and moved the second `product-card` element inside the `list-wrapper` element too.

```css
.list-wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  left-margin: 5em;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
}

.product-card {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="list-wrapper">
    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="product-name">Product Name</div>
        <div class="product-basic-description">Comes in many colors and sizes</div>
        <div class=product-price>300.00 $</div>
        <div class=product-image><img src="" alt="{{ image-description }}"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-card">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="product-name">Product Name</div>
        <div class="product-basic-description">Comes in many colors and sizes</div>
        <div class=product-price>300.00 $</div>
        <div class=product-image><img src="" alt="{{ image-description }}"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```